# Token Extensions program custom program error: 0x7dc8348c

Tags: token-2022, transfer-checked

I using instructions from here https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions, and getting error: **Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x7dc8348c** while sending transaction with createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is the [error](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/transfer-hook/interface/src/error.rs#L9-L10) you're encountering:

```
/// Incorrect account provided
#[error("Incorrect account provided")]
IncorrectAccount
```

There was an [issue](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/6064) with how the transfer hook offchain helper functions resolved accounts that might be causing the error. The issue is closed, but not sure if fixes have been published to `@solana/spl-token` yet.