how to transfer spl token with transfer-hook extension
I used the Solana Playground wallet to deploy a program and obtained the program ID. The ID is 6baxXgMr7HypeTBhN64rbrt31UwbSeRtsQQxGw1KBi5b. Then, I used the following script to create an SPL token.
//createandmint.js
const {
    clusterApiUrl,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
    Connection,
    Keypair,
    PublicKey,
    SystemProgram,
    Transaction,
    LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
} =require('@solana/web3.js');

const {
    ExtensionType,
    createInitializeMintInstruction,
    createInitializeTransferHookInstruction,
    mintTo,
    createAccount,
    getMintLen,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotent,
} =require("@solana/spl-token");
const bs58 = require("bs58");

(async () => {
    function generateExplorerTxUrl(txId) {
        return `https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txId}?cluster=devnet`;
    }
    const privateKeyString = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
    let privateKeyBytes = bs58.decode(privateKeyString);
// Import our keypair from the wallet file
    const payer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(privateKeyBytes));



    // const payer = Keypair.generate();
    const mintAuthority = payer;

    const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
    const mint = mintKeypair.publicKey;

    const extensions = [ExtensionType.TransferHook];
    const mintLen = getMintLen(extensions);
    const decimals = 9;

    const mintAmount = BigInt(1_000_000 * Math.pow(10, decimals)); // Mint 1,000,000 tokens
    const transferAmount = BigInt(1_000 * Math.pow(10, decimals)); // Transfer 1,000 tokens

    const transferHookProgramId = new PublicKey('6baxXgMr7HypeTBhN64rbrt31UwbSeRtsQQxGw1KBi5b')

    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');

    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, 2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    await connection.confirmTransaction({ signature: airdropSignature, ...(await connection.getLatestBlockhash()) });

    const mintLamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen);
    const mintTransaction = new Transaction().add(
        SystemProgram.createAccount({
            fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
            newAccountPubkey: mint,
            space: mintLen,
            lamports: mintLamports,
            programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
        createInitializeTransferHookInstruction(mint, payer.publicKey, transferHookProgramId, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID),
        createInitializeMintInstruction(mint, decimals, mintAuthority.publicKey, null, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID)
    );
    const newTokenTx = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, mintTransaction, [payer, mintKeypair], undefined);
    console.log("New Token Created:", generateExplorerTxUrl(newTokenTx));
    const owner = payer;
    const sourceAccount = await createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotent(connection, payer, mint, owner.publicKey, {}, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID);
    const mintSig = await mintTo(connection,payer,mint,sourceAccount,mintAuthority,mintAmount,[],undefined,TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID);
    console.log("Tokens Minted:", generateExplorerTxUrl(mintSig));

})()

https://explorer.solana.com/address/2ieG5FgkUS2VXKU8RKLePGJ5t18nGRUcEqJcr4jcgMjF?cluster=devnet
Now I want to transfer spl token to a new wallet,the spl token mint address is 2ieG5FgkUS2VXKU8RKLePGJ5t18nGRUcEqJcr4jcgMjF
//transfer.js
const {
        PublicKey,
        SystemProgram,
        Transaction,
        sendAndConfirmTransaction,
        Keypair, Connection, clusterApiUrl,
    } =require("@solana/web3.js");
    const {
        ExtensionType,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        getMintLen,
        createInitializeMintInstruction,
        createInitializeTransferHookInstruction,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
        createMintToInstruction,
        createTransferCheckedInstruction,
        getAssociatedTokenAddressSync,
        createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction,
    } =require("@solana/spl-token");
    const bs58 = require("bs58");
    
    const privateKeyString = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
    let privateKeyBytes = bs58.decode(privateKeyString);
    // Import our keypair from the wallet file
    const wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(privateKeyBytes));
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
    // Generate keypair to use as address for the transfer-hook enabled mint
    const mint = new PublicKey("2ieG5FgkUS2VXKU8RKLePGJ5t18nGRUcEqJcr4jcgMjF");
    const decimals = 9;
    const amount = 1 * 10 ** decimals;
    const bigIntAmount = BigInt(amount);
    
    const sourceTokenAccount = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mint,
        wallet.publicKey,
        false,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );
    
    // Recipient token account address
    const recipient = Keypair.generate();
    const destinationTokenAccount = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mint,
        recipient.publicKey,
        false,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );
    (async () => {
        const transferInstruction =
            await createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction(
                connection,
                sourceTokenAccount,
                mint,
                destinationTokenAccount,
                wallet.publicKey,
                bigIntAmount,
                decimals,
                [],
                "confirmed",
                TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
            );
    
        const transaction = new Transaction().add(
            transferInstruction
        );
    
        const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
            connection,
            transaction,
            [wallet],
            { skipPreflight: true }
        );
        console.log("Transfer Signature:", txSig);
    })()

npm install @solana/spl-token@0.4.3 and the result is
failed ({"err":{"InstructionError":[0,"IncorrectProgramId"]}})

Anything wrong here?

best follow this guide:
https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/transfer-hook
Here is a simple hello world example.
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/tokens/token-2022/transfer-hook/anchor/TransferHookHelloWorld
I cant really see an error in your code. I dont think you need to add these accounts:
transferInstruction.keys.push(
  {
    pubkey: program.programId, // Address of the Transfer-hook program
    isSigner: false,
    isWritable: false,
  },
  {
    pubkey: extraAccountMetaListPDA, // Address of the ExtraAccountMeta account
    isSigner: false,
    isWritable: false,
  }
);

Maybe you need to update to the newest spl-token version.
    "@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.3"

Maybe you need to redeploy the transfer hook program.

I apologize for being a beginner, but there has been an update to the question.
@jonas-h

Could you please try log all the keys of that instruction and then check if they are the correct ones?     console.log(
"Pushed keys:",
JSON.stringify(transferInstruction.keys, null, 2)
);

All the keys are fine.link

Pushed keys: [   {     "pubkey": "BtX8y6Vk6tYjC8Whorcz2DrU2QMGQu5vG6LA59vuZNsu",     "isSigner": false,     "isWritable": true   },   {     "pubkey": "2ieG5FgkUS2VXKU8RKLePGJ5t18nGRUcEqJcr4jcgMjF",     "isSigner": false,     "isWritable": false   },   {     "pubkey": "EG3ERQTBUcF2xjqZMGesBjvw5QishKYGByLrTYxaCNJ7",     "isSigner": false,     "isWritable": true   },   {     "pubkey": "74aC1TdARVnebeVB13rRGsJtvuQV18WLYmJnSDh1DGWJ",     "isSigner": true,     "isWritable": false   } ] 

Hmm could you maybe post the whole code in a repository?

on the explorer link in the comment above, it looks like the destination account doesn't exist. Make sure that both sender and recipient token accounts are created.

create a new account with createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,but still get an  error,({"err":{"InstructionError":[0,{"Custom":2110272652}]}})
tx
code:repository

error: 0x7dc8348c????

Does this help? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/token-extensions-program-custom-program-error-0x7dc8348c Did you upgrade solana spl allready? Did you create the additional meta account already?
